# SQLGrammarException

Tags: java, mysql, spring-data

Boa noite!
Alguém pode me ajudar com o erro no meu código, eu segui os passos do professor mas apresenta erro no meu e não no exemplo dele. Eu estou usando as mesma dependências. Segue o trecho do método e o erro.

```
public List<Person> findByLastName(String lastName){
    String jpql = "from Person p where p.lastName like ?";

    return find(jpql, lastName);
}   

private static void findByLastName() {
    List<Person> persons = new PersonDAO().findByLastName("Figueira");

    for (Person person : persons) {
        System.out.println(person.toString());      
    }
}
```

Dá esse erro:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from Person p where p.lastName like 'Figueira'' at line 1

Comment: Parece que você está tentando usar a JPQL como se fosse uma SQL. Embora sejam parecidas, as duas são mutuamente incompatíveis entre si e não devem ser misturadas. O que o método `find` faz?

Comment: Victor, o método "find" foi criado para retornar uma lista baseada em uma lista de parâmetros.

Answer (score 2):

Como você está usando `JPQL` do`JPA` você tem que colocar o `SELECT` para a sua `JPQL`. O `HQL` é quem aceita omitir o `SELECT`.

```
public List<Person> findByLastName(String lastName){
    String jpql = "SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE p.lastName LIKE ?";

    return find(jpql, lastName);
}
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.5.0.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html

Comment: LR10, minhas dependências do MySQL e Hibernate foram atualizadas para as versões recentes. eu coloquei como vc falou e deu o seguinte erro: [DEPRECATION] Encountered positional parameter near line 1, column 76 in HQL: [SELECT p FROM br.com.devmedia.revjpa.entity.Person p WHERE p.lastName LIKE ?].  Positional parameter are considered deprecated; use named parameters or JPA-style positional parameters instead.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown parameter position: 1.

Comment: Posta a implementação do seu método find(jpql, lastName);